# Flattening rows into a single row based on rules?

Tags: t-sql, flatten

I have a result set that looks something like this:

| customer | flag | date_from | date_to |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC123 | Y | 22/01/2020 | 21/02/2021 |
| ABC123 | N | 22/02/2021 | 31/03/2021 |
| ABC123 | Y | 01/04/2021 | 30/09/2021 |
| ABC123 | Y | 01/10/2021 | 31/03/2022 |
| ABC123 | Y | 01/04/2022 | 30/09/2022 |
| ABC123 | Y | 01/10/2022 | 01/01/9999 |

I want to 'flatten' it so that it outputs this:

| customer | flag | date_from | date_to |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC123 | Y | 22/01/2020 | 21/02/2021 |
| ABC123 | N | 22/02/2021 | 31/03/2021 |
| ABC123 | Y | 01/04/2021 | 01/01/9999 |

Is this possible?

Comment: Shall we play guess the rules? "I have"/"I want" questions without an explanation of how to get from input to output don't help us help you.

Comment: thanks for the feedback @HABO. Will try and find the words to explain my problem in more detail next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a gaps and islands problem.  One approach uses the difference in row numbers method:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer ORDER BY date_from) rn1,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer, flag ORDER BY date_from) rn2
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT
    customer,
    flag,
    MIN(date_from) AS date_from,
    MAX(date_to) AS date_to
FROM cte
GROUP BY
    customer,
    flag,
    rn1 - rn2
ORDER BY
    MIN(date_from);
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks, Tim. Appreciate the rapid response!